# iisdirinfo failing on iis7?

Tags: iis, nant, nantcontrib

When running iisdirinfo on iis7 I'm seeing an error

```
.dll,1,GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG

BUILD FAILED

   C:\iisinfo.build(9,2):
      Error retrieving info for virtual directory 'WebServices' on 'localhost:80' (wesite: Webservice).
      Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Total time: 0.5 seconds.
```

This is after displaying a number of the properties correctly. So I guess it's being tripped up by another property later on.

Anyone seen this or have any ideas on what could be causing the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I forked the repo and put some extra debug in and it seems like the failure was down to a null value for a property.

Using appcmd it looks like

```
   <redirectHeaders>
</redirectHeaders>
```

I've put a check for null into the code and will be submitting a pull request later today